# "/bin/sh: XX: command not found" error when trying to install development version of R fst package from github

Tags: r, linux, macos, clang, fst

I'm trying to install the development version of the [`fst` package](https://github.com/fstpackage/fst) from github. (I want the development version because it maintains column classes when saving data frames, whereas the current released version does not.)

Initially, installation failed due to lack of OpenMP support. I resolved this (I think) by following the steps [**here**](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/) for R 3.4.0 on OSX.

However, now I'm getting the following error: `/bin/sh: XX: command not found`. I've already set what are supposed to be the appropriate paths in the `~/.R/Makevars` file, so I'm not sure what to do next to resolve the error.

Here's my code and output:

**First attempt to install `fst`, before adding OpenMP support**

```
devtools::install_github("fstPackage/fst", ref = "develop")
```

> * installing *source* package ‘fst’ ...
>   ** libs
>   clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -I. -Ifstcore -Ifstcore/LZ4 -Ifstcore/ZSTD -Ifstcore/ZSTD/common -Ifstcore/ZSTD/decompress -Ifstcore/ZSTD/compress -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
>   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c FastStore.cpp -o FastStore.o
>   clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
>   make: *** [FastStore.o] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fst’

**Adding OpenMP support**

To add OpenMP support, I followed the steps [here](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/) for R 3.4.0, including installing `gfortran 6.1` from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS-11) and `clang` using the pre-built OSX GUI installer provided [here](https://uofi.app.box.com/v/r-macos-clang-pkg). Then, as instructed, I added the following to my `~/.R/Makevars` file:

```
CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11=$CXX
CXX14=$CXX
CXX17=$CXX
CXX1X=$CXX
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
```

**Second attempt to install `fst`**

I then ran the installation code again and got the following error:

```
devtools::install_github("fstPackage/fst", ref = "develop")
```

> * installing *source* package ‘fst’ ...
>   ** libs
>   XX -std=gnu++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
>   -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -I. -Ifstcore -Ifstcore/LZ4 -Ifstcore/ZSTD -Ifstcore/ZSTD/common -Ifstcore/ZSTD/decompress -Ifstcore/ZSTD/compress -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
>   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c FastStore.cpp -o FastStore.o
>   /bin/sh: XX: command not found
>   make: *** [FastStore.o]
>   Error 127 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fst’

In addition to the errors, I can see that the installation output begins with `clang++ -std=gnu++11 ...` in the first attempt and `XX -std=gnu++11 ...` in the second attempt. I'm guessing I need to tell R (or some other program) about the path to `clang`, but I'm not sure what path is needed or where to put it (and isn't the `Makevars` file supposed to take care of that?), or whether there are other issues that need to be fixed as well.

Here are some of the particulars about my system:

Macbook Pro, OSX Sierra (version 10.12.5)

RStudio version 1.0.153

R Session Info

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1      compiler_3.4.1  R6_2.2.2        tools_3.4.1     withr_1.0.2    
 [6] curl_2.8.1      memoise_1.1.0   git2r_0.19.0    digest_0.6.12   devtools_1.13.2
```

**UPDATE:** Based on @MarkPlotnick's comment, I changed Makevars to the following:

```
CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11=$(CXX)
CXX14=$(CXX)
CXX17=$(CXX)
CXX1X=$(CXX)
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
```

This resulted in the following error:

> * installing *source* package ‘fst’ ...
>   ** libs   /Users/eipi10/.R/Makevars:7: *** Recursive variable `CXX' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fst’

Comment: I thought `Makevars` was more like a make file. So the syntax would be  `CXX11=$(CXX)` etc.

Comment: In the time it took you to write (and update) the question you could have copied the `CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++` line down four times for the four other assignments -- and would have had time left to brew one nice coffee.

Comment: For what it is worth, I use `VER=` (ie currently empty), `CCACHE=ccache` and then both `CXX=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)` and `CXX11=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)` and that works just fine.

Comment: First of all @DirkEddelbuettel, I drink tea and I like it strong, so maybe I would have had time to copy `CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++` only one or two times. Second, I only vaguely understand what's going on under the hood with Linux and building packages from source and figuring out what the errors mean, so I just followed the instructions in the post I linked to. I'm going to try your suggestions and I'll report back--after I've brewed a cup of strong tea, that is.

Comment: Mmm, a nice cup of tea in the afternoon...and it's all the more satisfying as I watch the package install from source without errors. Thanks for your help @DirkEddelbuettel. For my edification (if you're willing to take time out from brewing coffee, cutting and pasting paths, or adding functionality to `Rcpp`), can you explain why your first comment worked and why your second comment accomplishes the same goal? (Please feel free to add any of this as an answer.)

Comment: Not entirely sure -- `make` can be hairy.  Same variables are more sacred than others; I think because R takes `CXX` as given it may be taken differently here.  Or maybe you simply had a another self-referencing definition somewhere...

Comment: Or explicitly define CXX11, CXX17, CXX1X as said in https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17331

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the issue and figured out the solution based on the comment by @Dirk in ["/bin/sh: XX: command not found" error when trying to install development version of R fst package from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380901/bin-sh-xx-command-not-found-error-when-trying-to-install-development-versio#comment77856871_45380901)

I explicitly set the libraries in .R/Makevars:

```
CXX11=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX14=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX17=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX1X=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
```

This worked for me when I encountered this problem, though on my Mac the path to the binary is `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++`)

Answer (score 0):

Today, I stumbled on this exact problem. Thanks to the advice given by [@Mark Plotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554472/mark-plotnick), I came up with a working `Makevars` file without having to copy/paste the full path of C++ compiler to all other `CXX` variables. The following `Makevars` file using the *GNU Makefile* format works fine:

```
CC:=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX:=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11:=$(CXX)
CXX14:=$(CXX)
CXX17:=$(CXX)
CXX1X:=$(CXX)
LDFLAGS:=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
```

Tested with using `devtools::install_github` to install packages that require compilation on macOS.

Note: because my Mac system uses the *GNU GCC* installed from *Homebrew*, the actual paths of the C and C++ compilers together with the library in my system are:

```
CC:=/usr/local/bin/gcc-12
CXX:=/usr/local/bin/g++-12
LDFLAGS:=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/lib/gcc/12
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/bin/bash: lz4c: command not found

sudo apt-get install liblz4c-tool
```